# Are there Geany temp files that contain some or all of my private content?

Tags: linux, geany

If Geany is closed gracefully are there automatically generated backup files or automatically generated temp files anywhere at all in the Linux file system? If Geany crashes are there backup or temp files  anywhere at all in the Linux file system?

I am not concerned about metadata. I am only concerned about temp files and backup files that contain some or all of the [cleartext](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleartext) of a file that is private to the Linux (Ubuntu) user account.

**Edit**

A description of what I have tried follows.

I see no clues about backups in edit>prefs>general>startup nor in ..prefs>general>miscellaneous nor in ..prefs>editor>features nor in ..prefs>files <strike>nor in ..prefs/various</strike>.

Editing a file and saving it and then issuing `ls -a` shows no backup file in the immediate directory.

**Edit**

The edit>prefs>various options are described here.
[Link](https://wiki.geany.org/config/all_you_never_wanted_to_know_about_file_saving) It appears that by default there is no backup file. A temp file is discussed but it does not say where the temp file is located and whether a clean-up happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606404/geany-ide-backup-copy-path this SO question might be of interest to you.